# Training SVM with word2vector data

Tags: python, nlp, svm, numpy-ndarray

Input text data is tokenised:

```
data['tokenised']
['hasan', 'minhaj', 'responds', 'netflix', 'pulling', 'episode', 'comedy', 'show', 'saudi', 'arab']
```

Data is padded with 0s to make all the tokenised texts of equal length (51 in this case):

```
len(data['tokenised'][0])
51
```

Word vectors of 100 dimensions are called:

```
embeddings_index = dict()
f = open('glove.6B.100d.txt')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()
```

Input data tokens are converted to their vector form:

```
def word2vec(tokens,max_size,dim):
    print(tokens)
    vec = np.zeros((max_size,dim))
    for ind,tok in enumerate(tokens):
        if(tok==0):
            vec[ind] = vec[ind]
        else:
            try:
                print(ind)
                vec[ind] = embeddings_index[tok]
            except KeyError:
                continue
return vec


data['w2v'][0]
array([[-0.41133001, -0.20108999, -0.54119998, ..., -0.67202002,
     0.14799   , -0.055051  ],
   [ 0.049478  ,  0.26212001, -0.78268999, ..., -0.14226   ,
    -0.32286   ,  0.13525   ],
   [-0.14078   ,  0.6573    ,  0.44602001, ..., -0.55290002,
     0.19839001,  0.39563   ],
   ...,
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Now I have each text with length 51 words and each word is represented by 100 dimensions vector (as shown in `data['w2v']`).

```
data['w2v'][0].shape
(51, 100)
```

All the arrays are of same dimension i.e. `(51, 100)` and all the array elements are of `float` type.

`data['w2v']` is a column of DataFrame.

Split data in train-test:

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data['w2v'], data['class'], test_size=0.2, stratify=data['class'])

x_train.shape    #series data type
(10248,)

x_train[7].shape   #2D array
(51, 100)
```

On fitting `SVM` model with 2D `numpy` array, I get below error:

```
model = LinearSVC(C=0.3)
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Note:
All the numpy array are of same shape `(51, 100)`.

Please suggest how this error should be handled?
How should I modify `x_train` so that model can be trained?

Answer (score 1):

Your `x_train` is currently three-dimensional. What you've done so far results in each training example `x_train[i]` being a (51,100) array, i.e. the shape of `x_train` is (n_samples, 51, 100).

When you're calling the `fit` method, `x_train` needs to have the shape `(n_samples, n_features)` (straight from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.fit)). So you need to reduce the 51x100 array for each input into a 1-d array/vector. You can do this by -

- Simply reshaping your (51,100) shaped arrays into (5100)-sized vectors, so that your `x_train` is shaped `(n_samples, 5100)`, or
- By combining the embeddings in some way, like averaging them or something to get a smaller number of features. For example, you could sum/average over each (51,100)-shaped array to get (51)-sized feature vectors. I mention this possibility because averaging word embeddings to get a sentence embedding is a very rough but commonly-used baseline technique (this is of course not generally applicable to convert input shapes).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Reducing dimensions to 51 sized vetors(second option) worked but the accuracy is only 76%. Need to find a better way for reducing dimention.